# Two Navigation Bars, top one aligned right, bottom one aligned left

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to create a navigation bar(s) identical to the one pictured. I am having issue with floating.

[This is the navigation bar(s) I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLe4J.png)

```
 <div class="upper_navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="youtube.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="li_top li_nav"><a href=#contact>Contact</a></li>
                <li class="li_top li_nav"><a href=#sign_up>Sign Up</a></li>
                <li class="li_top li_nav"><a href=#donate>Donate</a></li>
            </ul> 
    </div>

    <div id="main_navigation">
            <ul class="main_nav">
                <li><a href="#about" class="li_nav">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trips" class="li_nav">Trips</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects" class="li_nav">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#donations" class="li_nav">Donations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sponsors" class="li_nav">Sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="li_nav">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: please put some of ur piece of code

Comment: @MandarSant I don't have any CSS right now, Ive been trying and failing with my different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can make the `<ul>` and `<li>` inline-block so that it will display in the same line and then float your `.upper_navigation` to right and float your `#main_navigation` or `.main_nav` to left. In the example below I used the class of `<ul>`.

Here is an example of the css for that.

```
ul, li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.upper_navigation{
  float:right;
}
.main_nav{
  width:100%;
  float:left; // if you want center change the float to text-align:center
}
```

This is just how to float your navigations since you said that you are having problems with floating. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39rag22x/2/).

Answer (score 0):

is this output R U expecting

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #00457C;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.mainmenu {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>ABCDEF</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5</li>
      <li>Item6</li>
      <li>Item7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```